# mix deps.get error in elixr guardian after guardian installation

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I installed Guardian following a tutorial, using {:guardian, "~> 0.14"}.
when running mix deps.get
it gives this error:

```
** (Mix.Config.LoadError) could not load config config/dev.exs
** (CompileError) config/dev.exs:1: undefined function mix/1
(elixir) lib/code.ex:176: Code.eval_string/3
(mix) lib/mix/config.ex:180: Mix.Config.read!/2
(mix) lib/mix/config.ex:217: anonymous fn/3 in Mix.Config.read_wildcard!/2
```

This is my config/dev.exs file. I tried generating a secret key for guardian but it gave the sane issue

```
mix phoenix.gen.secretuse Mix.Config

config :sling, Sling.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 4000],
  debug_errors: true,
  code_reloader: true,
  check_origin: false,
  watchers: []

# Do not include metadata nor timestamps in development logs
config :logger, :console, format: "[$level] $message\n"

# Set a higher stacktrace during development. Avoid configuring such
# in production as building large stacktraces may be expensive.
config :phoenix, :stacktrace_depth, 20

# Configure your database
config :sling, Sling.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: "postgres",
  password: "postgres",
  database: "sling_dev",
  hostname: "localhost",
  pool_size: 10

# Configure Guardian
  config :guardian, Guardian


  import_config "dev.secret.exs"
```

Comment: Post your `config/dev.exs` file please

Comment: I have done that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `mix phoenix.gen.secret` from line #1 so as to be  `use Mix.Config`

Comment: didn't notice that since. Thank you

Comment: Your're welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct.